# How to auto log off a user in xp?

Tags: windows-xp

Is there a feature in xp that you auto log offs the computer after a certain time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [**Microsoft KB**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314999) which shows you how this can be done, using the winexit.scr screensaver (see below):

> *This step-by-step article describes how to automatically quit a user's running programs and to log the user off of a workstation after a specified time period.*
>
> How to Configure the Winexit.scr Screen Saver:
>
> 1. Use Windows Explorer to locate the Winexit.scr file in the Windows 2000
>    Resource Kit folder on your hard disk.
> 2. Right-click the Winexit.scr file, and then click Install.
> 3. The Display Properties dialog box appears with the Screen Saver tab
>    active. The Logoff Screen Saver entry
>    is automatically selected. Click
>    Settings.
> 4. Select the Force application termination check box to force
>    programs to quit.
> 5. In the Countdown for n seconds box, type the number of seconds for which
>    the logoff dialog box appears before
>    the user is logged off.
> 6. In the Logoff Message box, type the message that appears during the logoff
>    countdown. Click OK.
> 7. In the Display Properties dialog box, click Preview.
> 8. You see the Auto Logoff dialog box. It displays the logoff message and the
>    countdown timer. Click Cancel.
> 9. Click OK.

To save you having to download the whole [**Windows 2000 Resource Kit**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229), head over to petri.co.il and grab the single zipped up file called [**Winexit**](http://www.petri.co.il/download_free_reskit_tools.htm) from there.

Comment: The link on `petri.co.il` is broken.